# 3D Plotting with 3D numpy array with given set of datas

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, matplotlib

I will be glad if someone can help me. I have 3 x 3 x 3 = 27 data points. I could make into 3 x 3 x 3 numpy array in python by using

```
In>>a = np.array([1,2,3,-4,5,6,-2,5,7,-5,0,9,2,-3,4,5,-1,1,2,-4,1,5,-9,-4,6,-3,5])
In>>a.reshape((3,3,3))
out>> array(
   [[[ 1,  2,  3],
    [-4,  5,  6],
    [-2,  5,  7]],

   [[-5,  0,  9],
    [ 2, -3,  4],
    [ 5, -1,  1]],

   [[ 2, -4,  1],
    [ 5, -9, -4],
    [ 6, -3,  5]]])
```

I want to create a 3D plot on this array (Basically I want multiple 2D planes for z= 0,1,2) and also I want to make a plane that slices the bulk of the 3D plot.

Comment: Have a look at [mayavi](http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/), it is built for using with numpy arrays. Some examples [here](http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/mlab_case_studies.html). I guess using mayavi is a bit overkill for a 3x3 array, but I don't know if matplotlib supports drawing 2D planes in 3D volumes.

Comment: In this case, I already have scalar field data generated by some other software. I guess each and every data point is indexed by a.reshape. I saw mayavi examples, it looks like there is a scalar function which generates data, which is different from the present case.

Comment: It's unclear exactly what you're looking for.  Plotting 3D data inherently involves slicing, no matter what language or processing you're using.  The closest thing to a clear question is "Basically I want multiple 2D planes for z= 0,1,2)" ... but it's still too vague: What have you tried and why didn't it work?  Do you want 3 individual 2D images, or do you want some sort of layered 3D visualization?  Please be specific.